# Crystal report viewer is not able to display when publish to server visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, iis-6, publish

i need to ask some question about crystal report. I have successfully run crystal report   locally with visual studio 2010, But when i deploy to the server. It causes me an error.

The crystal report viewer is no able to display report .It only give me an blank page.By the way I am using window server 2003 and IIS 6.

I also has installed the crystal report run-time on my server. Did i miss any step for configure? Please guide me with some ideas. Thanks

Here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Server.MapPath("~/Module/Report/CrystalReport1.rpt");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues that need to be handled:

You need to run "Verify Database" on the report again on the server if you are using SQL Server Native Client.

These links may help further:

[Crystal reports in ASP.NET](http://www.csharpaspnetarticles.com/2009/07/creating-crystal-reports-in-aspnet.html)

[Crystal report error (Load report failed) in asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1702597.aspx/1)

** Edited **
[Report not running via IIS but runs well through VS2005](http://forums.asp.net/t/1744060.aspx/1)

I also remember that I solved the issue after configuring Crystal Reports to run as Local Service instead of Network Service in IIS and also by using Integrated Security = True in connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post. but For anyone still looking for the answer:

You need to register crystal reports in page markup

```
<% @ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
    Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

Set the property '**Copy to Output Directory'** of the report to **'Copy always'**

the path of the file in the crystalreportsource will be ~/bin/YOURFOLDER/YOURFILE

```
<CR: CrystalReportSource ID ="CrystalReportSource1" runat ="server">
            <Report FileName="~/bin/oilmovement/rptOMDayEnd.rpt">
            </Report>
        </CR: CrystalReportSource>
```

Now the report should work

Comment: thanks. I solve by other solution. you may help other people also

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround. If you just copy the RPT files from your development machine and replace the published RPT files at server. That will solve the issue.

of-course you also need to install the run-time (v13.0 for VS2010, and 13.0.5 for VS2012)